# The menu will not open on the first click reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a navbar in which there is a button that opens a menu on full screen and in the menu there is a dismiss button. now everything works except the button that opens the menu. It works on double click and not from the first click. it was working until I made the dismiss button

this is the navbar code 
**NavBar.js**

```
function Navbar() {
  const [openProfile, setOpenProfile] = useState(false);
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);



  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <div className="navbar-menu">
        <button className="float-on-hover" onClick={()=> setOpenMenu(!openMenu)}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faNavicon} className="fa-2x" />
        </button>
        {openMenu && <Menu /> }
      </div>

      <div className="navbar-user">
        <button className="float-on-hover" onClick={() => setOpenProfile(!openProfile)}>
          {" "}
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle} className="fa-2x" />
        </button>

        {openProfile && <Dropdown />}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

This is the menu code 
**Menu.js**

```
function Menu() {
  const [closeMenu, setCloseMenu] = useState(true);

  function dismissButton ()
  {
    setCloseMenu(!closeMenu) 
  }
  return (
 
   <>
    {closeMenu &&
   <div className="menu__page">
      <div className="close__button">
        <button onClick={dismissButton}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClose} className="fa-2x" /></button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="menu__content">
        <div className="menu__items">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                HOME
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                STANDARD
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                PREMIUM
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="# " className="link__item">
                LUXURY
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                WISHLIST
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                CONTACT
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is you have two methods of hiding your menu. One from inside the menu itself, and one from the button to reveal the menu.

When you click the menu button, and the menu opens, then you click the dismiss menu inside the menu, you end up with `openMenu=true` and `closeMenu=true` so the button shows the Menu component, which internally hides itself.

Then when you click the menu button, it toggles to `openMenu=false`, which also removes the Menu component (resetting `closeMenu`).
Then when you click again, it toggles to `openMenu=true` again, showing the menu.

I recommend only having one location where you decide if the menu is visible or not. In this simple case, it's probably easiest to pass in a "closeMenu" function to the menu itself, which should be called by the Menu component, to edit the navbar's `openMenu` variable.

eg. I'd add:

```js
const closeMenu = () => {
  setOpenMenu(false);
}
```

to the NavBar, then pass this into the Menu component:

```js
        {openMenu && <Menu closeMenu={closeMenu} /> }
```

Then modify the Menu component to accept it:

```js
function Menu({closeMenu}) {
  function dismissButton ()
  {
    closeMenu(); 
  }
  return (
   <div className="menu__page">
      <div className="close__button">
        <button onClick={dismissButton}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClose} className="fa-2x" /></button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="menu__content">
        <div className="menu__items">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                HOME
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                STANDARD
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                PREMIUM
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="# " className="link__item">
                LUXURY
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                WISHLIST
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#" className="link__item">
                CONTACT
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: I haven't run this myself, but the principle is to only ever store the menu's show/hide variable in one place. If you were using Redux, I'd recommend putting it in the store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it didn't work it says closeMenu is not a function but now I know then problem. thank you

Comment: Oops. That's true, in the Menu component you need to put the closeMenu function inside curly brackets to allow it to be passed as a named parameter. I have edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem was ending up with **openMenu=true** and **closeMenu=true** I changed the code as below

```
function Navbar() {
  const [openProfile, setOpenProfile] = useState(false);
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(false);


  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <div className="navbar-menu">
        <button className="float-on-hover" onClick={()=> setOpenMenu(!openMenu)}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faNavicon} className="fa-2x" />
        </button>
        {openMenu && <>
   <div className="menu__page">
      <div className="close__button">
        <button onClick={() => setOpenMenu(false)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faClose} className="fa-2x" /></button>
      </div>
      
      <div className="menu__content">
        <div className="menu__items">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="/" className="link__item">
                HOME
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="/standard" className="link__item">
                STANDARD
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/premium" className="link__item">
                PREMIUM
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="/luxury" className="link__item">
                LUXURY
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              {" "}
              <a href="/whishlist" className="link__item">
                WISHLIST
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/contact" className="link__item">
                CONTACT
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</> }
      </div>

      <div className="navbar-user">
        <button className="float-on-hover" onClick={() => setOpenProfile(!openProfile)}>
          {" "}
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle} className="fa-2x" />
        </button>

        {openProfile && <Dropdown />}
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

I included the menu in the navbar and now it works